# Named Services in IoC Containers - A Bad Idea?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject

It seems like a bad idea to use service keys (or 'named services') when composing a container.

Using named services requires us to either annotate our constructor parameters with matching keys (thus coupling with a container), or to perform additional wiring for each of our services (thus loosing a lot of automation from the container).

For example, I currently have the following interface which is implemented by the following classes:

- `IListSerializer`

  - `CheckboxListSerializer`
  - `TreeViewListSerializer`

I also have countless classes which depend on either one or both of these classes. However, AFAIK I should be referencing the `IListSerializer` as my dependency rather than the implementations. This means I have to use keys/names to differentiate between them, which is where it starts to get ugly.

I can see my options as being one of the following:

- Annotate the constructor parameters (dependencies) with keys. Couples with IoC Container.
- Perform manual wiring in composition root. Adds repetitive bloat.
- Reference the classes instead of the interface. Seems like a hack just to satisfy the IoC container.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Good containers let you annotate the parameters without coupling to the container.

Comment: I don't understand the scenario: you're saying you have some classes that specifically want a CheckboxListSerializer and some a TreeViewListSerializer? So why not define a more specific interface for each one that differentiates between them? What are you hoping to gain by DIing at that level?

Comment: @Rup's comment should really be an answer. Defining an ICheckboxListSerializer and ITreeViewListSerializer is a good option.

Comment: @Martinho - I would be interested to see how. Which assembly defines the aforementioned parameter attributes? If you reply 'Autofac.*' then you've misjudged what I meant by coupling... there shouldn't be a single wiff of container technology in the implementation.

Comment: Ninject lets you use your own attributes. When you configure the container, you just tell it which attributes are those.

Comment: @Pet & @Rup - What if their definitions are identical? Should I define new interfaces just because their behaviours differ? This doesn't sound right to me, but I'm open to correction.

Comment: @Rup - Another scenario is the 'primitive data type dependency'. Let's say we have a dependency on an integer... surely we need to use named services for this, or would you box them all into interfaces?

Comment: Regarding primitives: I would not take them as dependencies. See my best practices: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/inversion-of-control-containers-best-practices/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, the Liskov Substitution Principle is a very useful guide when designing components and services for IoC. If two implementations of a service can't be used interchangeably at runtime, then the service is too general to be meaningful. In this scenario I'd look at using something along the lines of `IListSerializer<T>` if that is an option for you.

However, if you want to use named services, this is easy and unintrusive to set up with Autofac.

First, register each serializer with its name:

```
builder.RegisterType<CheckBoxListSerializer>()
    .Named<IListSerializer>("checkBoxSerializer");
builder.RegisterType<TreeViewListSerializer>()
    .Named<IListSerializer>("treeViewSerializer");
```

Then, add a globally-available parameter that uses the constructor parameter name to choose the right implementation. We can do this with a module:

```
class NamedParameterResolutionModule<TService> : Module
{
    Parameter _attachedParameter = new ResolvedParameter(
        (pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(TService),
        (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<TService>(pi.Name));

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry registry,
        IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += (s, e) => {
            e.Parameters = new[] { _attachedParameter }.Contact(e.Parameters);
        };
    }
}
```

Register the module like so:

```
builder.RegisterModule<NamedParameterResolutionModule<IListSerializer>>();
```

Components will then get a serializer depending on the constructor parameter name:

```
class SomeComponent : ...
{
    public SomeComponent(IListSerializer checkBoxSerializer) { ...
}
```

Comment: Fantastic answer Nicholas. You've improved my understanding of both LSP and Autofac. Great quote: 'If two implementations of a service can't be used interchangeably at runtime, then the service is too general to be meaningful.'